# Es posible cambiar de ruta al obtener el resultado cuando se fusiona un video y audio usando la librería ffmpeg?

Tags: nodejs, ffmpeg

estoy trabajando ffmpeg y nodejs, al obtener el resultado de la fusión del video y audio, automáticamente  lo obtengo en la carpeta raiz donde estoy trabajando actualmente, dando como resultado esto: "video.mkv"
capturar el resultado y pasarlo hacia otra ruta  seria posible?
esto es lo que tengo en codigo donde crea el archivo "video.mkv":

```
    const ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg-static');
    const cp = require('child_process');

    const ffmpegProcess = cp.spawn(ffmpeg,[
  // Remove ffmpeg's console spamming
  '-loglevel', '8', '-hide_banner',
  // Redirect/Enable progress messages
  '-progress', 'pipe:3',
  // Set inputs
  '-i', //'pipe:4',
  '-i', //'pipe:5',
  // Map audio & video from streams
  '-map', '0:a',
  '-map', '1:v',
  // Keep encoding
  '-c:v', 'copy',
  // Define output file,
  'video.mkv'
], {
  windowsHide: true,
  stdio: [
    /* Standard: stdin, stdout, stderr */
    'inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit',
    /* Custom: pipe:3, pipe:4, pipe:5 */
    'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe',
  ],
});

audio.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[4]);
video.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[5]);
```

le agredezco su ayuda de antemano.

Comment: usas alguna librería e específico? sino, qué tiene la variable `ffmpeg`? Si añades un poco mas de código quizás pueda ayudarte

Comment: @Japsz correcto, acabo de actualizar la información con las librerías que se utiliza que seria ffmpeg-static y  child-process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si mal no me equivoco, lo único que necesitas hacer es agregar la [ruta relativa](https://denovatoanovato.net/rutas-relativas-y-rutas-absolutas/) cuando defines el archivo de output. Aquí unos ejemplos:

```
// lo guarda una carpeta llamada NuevaCarpeta ubicada en el mismo directorio desde donde se ejecutó el comando 'node', si la carpeta no existe, la crea
'./NuevaCarpeta/video.mkv',


// la guarda una carpeta atrás desde donde se ejecutó el comando 'node',
'../video.mkv',
```

Aparte, podrías usar la opción `cwd` de [child_proccess.spawn(...)](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) para cambiar el directorio base desde donde ejecutará el proceso hijo que crea tu archivo:

```
const ffmpegProcess = cp.spawn(ffmpeg,[
  // Remove ffmpeg's console spamming
  '-loglevel', '8', '-hide_banner',
  // Redirect/Enable progress messages
  '-progress', 'pipe:3',
  // Set inputs
  '-i', //'pipe:4',
  '-i', //'pipe:5',
  // Map audio & video from streams
  '-map', '0:a',
  '-map', '1:v',
  // Keep encoding
  '-c:v', 'copy',
  // Define output file,
  'video.mkv'
], {
  cwd: '/home/root/carpetaDestino', //se creará video.mkv en esta ruta siempre 
  windowsHide: true,
  stdio: [
    /* Standard: stdin, stdout, stderr */
    'inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit',
    /* Custom: pipe:3, pipe:4, pipe:5 */
    'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe',
  ],
});
```

Puedes usar una combinación de la opción `cwd` y la ruta relativa para lograr el resultado que necesites. Espero te sirva!